# Accessing Dictionary in jinja2

Tags: python, django, dictionary, jinja2

```
{% for blog in data %}
    {% with current_ids=blog.blog_id %}
    {{ like_ids }}
    {{ current_ids }}
    {{ like_ids['bar'] }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

in above code {{ **like_ids** }} prints {'foo': [], 'bar': [<User: foo@bar.com>]}
{{ **current_ids** }} prints foo || bar
{{ **like_ids['bar']** }} throws error "Could not parse the remainder: '['bar']' from 'like_ids['bar']'"

i tried **like_ids.bar** and it prints [<User: foo@bar.com>]
but,
**like_ids.current_ids** doesn't print anything

tried set instead of with and the problem still exists

```
def bloglist(request):
like_ids = {}
blog_data = Blog.objects.select_related('published_by').filter(status='Published').all()
for blog in blog_data:
    blog.comment = blog.blogcomment_set.select_related('commented_by').all()
    blog.like = blog.bloglike_set.select_related('liked_by').all()
    like_ids[blog.blog_id] = [like.liked_by for like in blog.like]
args = {
    'data': blog_data,
    'like_ids': like_ids
}
print(args)
return render(request, 'bloglist.html', args)
```

This is my views.py code

Comment: show us your context, view code, `{{ like_ids }}` where does this `{{ like_ids }}` comes from?

Comment: like_ids comes from views

Comment: show us the views.py code./ what's the structure of it?

Comment: I have updated in question with views.py code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function,

```
def bloglist(request):
like_ids = {}
blog_data = Blog.objects.select_related('published_by').filter(status='Published').all()
for blog in blog_data:
    blog.comment = blog.blogcomment_set.select_related('commented_by').all()
    blog.like = blog.bloglike_set.select_related('liked_by').all()
    like_ids[blog.blog_id] = [like.liked_by for like in blog.like]
args = {
    'data': blog_data,
    'like_ids': like_ids
}
print(args)
return render(request, 'bloglist.html', args)
```

To below.

```
def bloglist(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.select_related('published_by').filter(status='Published').all()
    args = {
        'data': blog_data,

    }
    print(args)
    return render(request, 'bloglist.html', args)
```

Change template as below.

```
{% for blog in data %}

  {% for like in blog.bloglike_set.all %}
    {{ like.id }}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ blog.id }}


{% endfor %}
```

Template explanation.

```
{% for blog in data %}

# ALL THE IDs OF LIKES OF CURRENT BLOG
  {% for like in blog.bloglike_set.all %}
    {{ like.id }}
  {% endfor %}


# CURRENT BLOG ID
  {{ blog.id }}



{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can access any related model field by just `blog_data = Blog.objects.select_related('published_by').filter(status='Published').all()` query. Inside template.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dictionary like below.

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in data.items %} 
  <li>{{key}} - {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Why you do this,

```
{% for blog in data %}
    {% with current_ids=blog.blog_id %}
    {{ like_ids }}
    {{ current_ids }}
```

While you can do this.

```
{% for blog in data %}
    {{ like_ids }}
    {{ blog.blog_id }}
```

Comment: yeah, even tried like_ids[blog.blog_id] this throws error Could not parse the remainder
and like_ids.blog.blog_id doesn't print anything

Comment: show us views.py code please.

Comment: Updated question with views.py code